# Why does "eslint --print-config blah.js > outfile.json" result in invalid configuration rules?

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslint

Following this guide, I have tried to create an extracted rule set except I am extending from eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier instead of eslint-config-airbnb-typescript: -

```
module.exports = {
extends: "airbnb-typescript-prettier"
}
```

When I run `eslint --print-config blah.js > outfile.json` I indeed get the output file but when I try to use the config in that output file in my .eslintrc.js, I get errors such as the following: -

```
Error: .eslintrc.js:
Configuration for rule "import/no-cycle" is invalid:
Value null should be integer.
```

Which refers to the rule config from the `--print-config` command of: -

```
"import/no-cycle": [
"error",
{
"maxDepth": null
}
],
```

So why is `--print-config` outputting invalid configs and is there any way to stop it from happening so I have a valid rule set? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a bug in ESLint v7.3.0

A temporary fix would be to downgrade ESLint to v7.2.0

```
- "eslint": "^7.3.0"
+ "eslint": "7.2.0"
```

Reference: [GitHub](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2227#issuecomment-646843880)